# MQTT broker windows

Tags: windows, server, mqtt, broker, mosquitto

I've been trying to set up MQTT broker on windows but with not results. I am not very experience in this topic. I've downloaded the mosquitto files from http://mosquitto.org/download/ but I haven't get the server running. I downloaded the binary files for windows and followed the instructions but I can only get the broker run but I can't subscribe. It says "pthreadVC2.dll is missing" and I've tried install it but I do not know how to do it. If you are able to suggest me how to get the broker running I appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Please see http://git.eclipse.org/c/mosquitto/org.eclipse.mosquitto.git/tree/readme-windows.txt

> ### Dependencies - win32
>
> - OpenSSL
>     Link: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
>     Install "Win32 OpenSSL "
>     Required DLLs: libeay32.dll ssleay32.dll
> - pthreads
>     Link: ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32
>     Install "pthreads-w32--release.zip
>     Required DLLs: pthreadVC2.dll

If this doesn't solve the problem, you may need to install Visual Studio redistributables. The packaged Mosquitto versions are compiled with Visual Studio 2010, which can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is what I've been trying but I can no get to install the pthreadVC2.dll

Comment: You should just need to download the zip, extract, and copy pthreadVC2.dll to the mosquitto_[sp]ub directory.

Comment: Hi. I get the following error those steps. The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Comment: I've added some more details to the answer.

Comment: Worked for me, just had to chose the right pthreadVC2.dll to add to mosquitto directory. In my case it was the x86. If I try the x64 I got the same complains as you @Mani

Comment: Died in dependency hell. I get back to linux for my broker using `apt-get install mosquitto mosquitto_clients`

Answer (score 3):

Check this link:  https://sivatechworld.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/step-by-step-installing-and-configuring-mosquitto-with-windows-7/

You have to include these files(libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll and  pthreadVC2.dll) in mosquitto folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto) and reinstall the mosquitto server. After reinstalling check the services to see if Mosquitto is running as a service. Then use the command  netstat -an in command prompt. That will show the active connection and its status.

The above link gives a step by step installation procedure.

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12403756)

Comment: @QoP the essential part is there, right below the link.

Comment: Be note to use the correct installer of Win32 OpenSSL (1.0.2k), otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

There's the open-source and scalable MQTT broker I'm personnally involved with: [emitter.io](https://emitter.io). It's built using **.NET Core and LibUV** - [github.com/emitter-io/emitter](https://github.com/emitter-io/emitter).

There's also a nice list of MQTT brokers available here: https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/servers

Answer (score 0):

this link will bring you to the pThreads: ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest/dll/x86/

where you can donwload it directly:

and then copy-paste the dll in your mosquito installation 
folder
[image]